# EF6 - foreign key references back to same table failing in seed method

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, entity-framework-migrations

I've got a bunch of tables with the standard CreatedByUser/LastModifiedByUser info, including the User table itself.

However, I don't seem to be able to add EF6 seed data for it as I am always getting the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values

the User class looks like this (stripped down quite a bit):

```
Public Class User

    Public Sub New()
        UsersCreated = New HashSet(Of User)
        UsersModified = New HashSet(Of User)
    End Sub

    <Key>
    Public Property Id As Integer


    <ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")>
    Public Property CreatedByUser As AspNetUser

    Public Property CreatedByUserId As Integer?

    Public Property CreatedDate As Date?

    <ForeignKey("LastModifiedByUserId")>
    Public Property LastModifiedByUser As AspNetUser

    Public Property LastModifiedByUserId As Integer?

    Public Property LastModifiedDate As Date?

    Public Overridable Property UsersCreated As ICollection(Of AspNetUser)

    Public Overridable Property UsersModified As ICollection(Of AspNetUser)

End Class
```

I also have the following two rules in my DbContext.OnModelCreating:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of AspNetUser)() _
            .HasOptional(Function(e) e.CreatedByUser) _
            .WithMany(Function(e) e.UsersCreated) _
            .HasForeignKey(Function(e) e.CreatedByUserId) _
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of AspNetUser)() _
            .HasOptional(Function(e) e.LastModifiedByUser) _
            .WithMany(Function(e) e.UsersModified) _
            .HasForeignKey(Function(e) e.LastModifiedByUserId) _
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```

I know this and the DataAnnotations on the User class are probably redundant, but I have tried one, then the other then both, and none of it works.

I can create the DB, but when I try to create a new user, with CreatedByUser and LastModifiedByUser both set to "Nothing", it fails with the above error.

Here is the seed method snippet:

```
            Dim newUser = New User() With
                            {
                                .CreatedByUser = Nothing,
                                .LastModifiedByUser = Nothing
                            }

            context.Users.Add(newUser)
            context.SaveChanges()
```

Am I missing something here? I've no idea why it fails like this when I am setting those Users to Nothing in a nullable field. I could understand if I was trying to reference an object that hadn't been created yet, but I'm not.

Comment: What's your context look like? Are you inheriting from IdentityDbContext? If it is separate, you will need DbSets in your context for the user class.

Comment: Are you sure this snippet causes the exception? What else is in the seed method?